# How to merge two Option[String] variables into one when using flatMap in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following class:

```
case class Profile(email: Option[String],
                   firstName: Option[String],
                   lastName: Option[String],
                   fullName: Option[String])
```

Now I want to remove the `fullName` attribute because it's redundant. However, I have a method in my class `User` which returns the `fullName`:

```
case class User(id: UUID, profiles: List[Profile]) {
// Skipped some lines
  def fullName(loginInfo:LoginInfo) = profileFor(loginInfo).flatMap(_.fullName)
}
```

Now I am trying to replace the `.flatMap(_.fullName)` part with a concatenation of `firstName` + `lastName`. How can this be done? Do I need make a new `Option[String]`, like this:

```
def fullName(loginInfo:LoginInfo) = {
  val firstName = profileFor(loginInfo).flatMap(_.firstName)
  val lastName = profileFor(loginInfo).flatMap(_.lastName)
  val fullName : Option[String] = Some(firstName + " " + lastName)
  fullName
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a good application of a `for`.

```
case class User(id: UUID, profiles: List[Profile]) {
// Skipped some lines
  def fullName(loginInfo:LoginInfo): Option[String] = for {
    profile <- profileFor(loginInfo)
    first <- profile.firstName
    last <- profile.lastName
  } yield s"$first $last"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I really like this approach. `last <- profile.firstName` should be `last <- profile.lastName` instead.

Comment: This yields `None` if `firstName` or `lastName` is `None` instead of leaving it blank and inserting the separating space only if necessary, as in Synesso's answer.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but this would result in None if either first or last name were None.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet that is correct. This specific requirement isn't mentioned in the question, but I think that would be the correct behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one approach

```
List(firstName, lastName).flatten match {
  case Nil => None
  case xs => Some(xs.mkString(" "))
}
```

quick testing in the REPL...

```
scala> def fullName(fn: Option[String], ln: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
     |   List(fn, ln).flatten match {
     |     case Nil => None
     |     case xs => Some(xs.mkString(" "))
     |   }
     | }
fullName: (fn: Option[String], ln: Option[String])Option[String]

scala> fullName(None, None)
res3: Option[String] = None

scala> fullName(Some("a"), None)
res4: Option[String] = Some(a)

scala> fullName(None, Some("b"))
res5: Option[String] = Some(b)

scala> fullName(Some("a"), Some("b"))
res6: Option[String] = Some(a b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, if I am using your suggested approach, I would still need to use `.flatMap` twice to get `firstName` and `lastName` and then make a `List` or is there a better approach?

Comment: There is no `flatMap` needed in this answer. You just make a `List` of `Option[String]` items and then flatten it.

Answer (score 2):

`map2` (see chapter 4 of "[the red book](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)") affords you some abstraction:

```
def map2[A, B, C](oa: Option[A], ob: Option[B])(f: (A, B) => C): Option[C] =
  for {
    a <- oa
    b <- ob
  } yield f(a, b)
```

Then, leaving the `LoginInfo` stuff out (because you didn't define `profileFor` anywhere), you can simply define `fullName` as

```
def fullName: Option[String] = map2(firstName, lastName) { _ + " " + _ }
```

Comment: Same remark as for another answer: this yields `None` if `firstName` or `lastName` is `None` instead of leaving it blank and inserting the separating space only if necessary, as in Synesso's answer.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Correct. Whether what you describe is the desired behaviour is unclear to me, though.

Answer (score 2):

We can treat `Option` as a collection and get what you're looking for in a simple one-liner:

```
val firstName: Option[String] = Some("John")
val lastName: Option[String] = Some("Doe")
val fullName: Option[String] = (firstName ++ lastName).reduceOption(_ + " " + _) // Some("John Doe")
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a [blog post](https://blog.yuvalitzchakov.com/reducing-two-options-in-scala/) not long ago with a couple of native Scala options to do that.

The one I liked the most is similar to [@Pawels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318372/1870803) only using `reduceLeftOption`:

```
scala> val firstName = Some("yuval")
firstName: Some[String] = Some(yuval)

scala> val lastName = Some("itzchakov")
lastName: Some[String] = Some(itzchakov)

scala> (firstName ++ lastName).reduceLeftOption((a,b) => s"$a $b")
res10: Option[String] = Some(yuval itzchakov)
```

This approach is nice because it works when either of the `Option[T]` is `None`:

```
scala> val lastName: Option[String] = None
lastName: Option[String] = None

scala> (firstName ++ lastName).reduceLeftOption((a,b) => s"$a $b")
res11: Option[String] = Some(yuval)
```

Another nice property of this is that it can work for *N* elements when using varargs as well:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def reduce[T](options: Option[T]*)(f: (T, T) => T) = {
  options.flatten.reduceLeftOption(f)
}
reduce(Some(1), Some(1), Some(2), Some(4))(_+_)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

reduce: [T](options: Option[T]*)(f: (T, T) => T)Option[T]
res0: Option[Int] = Some(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think from oop perspective, you should keep `fullName` in `Profile` class, but as a method and from your `User` class just delegate it to `Profile`.

You can use any solution already given, I will post mine, using scalaz and applicative builder, it is similar to `map2`, just more general, as you can join any (well, not really any, but a reasonable amount as you have to pass the function that takes same number of arguments as the number of objects you want apply it to) number of options or other applicatives.

```
@ case class Profile(firstName: Option[String], lastName: Option[String]) {
  def fullName: Option[String] = (firstName |@| lastName)(_ + " " + _)
}

@ Profile("A".some, "B".some).fullName 
res2: Option[String] = Some("A B")
@ Profile("A".some, none).fullName 
res3: Option[String] = None
@ Profile(none, "B".some).fullName 
res4: Option[String] = None
@ Profile(none, none).fullName 
res5: Option[String] = None
```